# Twig template variables not displaying?

Tags: twig

I access the twig instance, and render the template like so:

```
return $this->template->render('login.html', array(
    'name' => 'John Smith',
    'age' => 32,
    'location' => 'Egypt'
));
```

Here is the template side of things

```
Hello, my name is {{ name }}, my age is {{ age }}, and my location is {{ location }}.
```

Currently prints out

```
Hello, my name is , my age is , and my location is .
```

Should print out

```
Hello, my name is John Smith, my age is 32, and my location is Egypt.
```

Comment: Exactly what kind of object is `template`?

Comment: It's an instance of the `Twig_Environment` class, I thought the `render` method made that clear, sorry.

Comment: Just checking as [`Twig_Template`](https://twig.symfony.com/api/2.x/Twig_Template.html#method_render) also has a `render()` method

Comment: What Phil says. Could u do a `var_dump` of `$this->template` to be sure it's the `Twig_Environment` and not a `Twig_Template`, otherwise you just need to do `$this->template->render(['name' => 'John...`